# Error while creating a folder in sharepoint library using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using below script to create a folder:

```
$folder = $dList.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
    $folder["Title"] = "Test"
    $folder.Update();
```

Error: Invalid item data - missing fileref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this PowerShell to get rid of missing FileRef issue:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://aissp2013/sites/Team
$dList = $web.Lists["Doc2"]
$folder = $dList.AddItem($dList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, "Folder2")
$folder["Title"] = "Test"
$folder.Update()
```

This will create a folder with Name "Folder2" and Title as "Test"

Comment: I wish I would get lessons from you on powershell.. :)