# Creating files in Document library in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

I am using below script to copy files from one library to another:

```
$SourceWebURL = "http://sitecollection/sites/site" 
$SourceLibraryTitle = "doclib" 
$DestinationWebURL = "http://sitecollection/sites/site" 
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "doclib" 
$ssite = Get-SPSite $SourceWebURL
$sweb = $ssite.OpenWeb("subsite")
$dsite = Get-SPSite $DestinationWebURL 
$dweb = $dsite.OpenWeb("Archivesubsite")
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle} 
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle} 
$AllFolders = $sList.Folders 
$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder 
$RootItems = $RootFolder.files 

foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
echo $Folder.url
    foreach($Item in $Folder)
    {
        $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary() 
            $dFile  = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($Item.Name, $sBytes, $true) 
        $dFile.Update() 
    }
}
```

I want to loop in each folder in doclib and create the files in folders in destination library.
Error I am getting is : You cannot called a method on null valued expression.

UPDATED after Nadeem's comment:

$AllFolders = $sList.Folders 
foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
    foreach($file in $Folder.Folder.Files)
    {
        write-Host "Hello"
        $sBytes = $file.OpenBinary() 
    $dFolder = $dlist.ParentWeb.GetFolder($dWeb.Url + "/" + $dList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $Folder.Name)
        $dFile  = $dFolder.Files.Add($dFolder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, $sBytes, $true)
    }
}
$dList.Update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to consider here. As is clear, you want to copy the documents from Source library to destination library and also preserve the folder structure. Documents can reside directly inside the source library at the root location. This folder is called `Root Folder` in SharePoint and it can be retrieved using `$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder`. Documents can also reside inside actual folders. These folders can be retrieved using `$AllFolders = $sList.Folders`. Here is a way to copy the documents from  all the folders except root folder of the source library to the root folder in destination library. Note that, ideally you will need to create a folder structure first before adding the file in it. However, I have already answered that [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130058/error-while-creating-a-folder-in-sharepoint-library-using-powershell)

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://aissp2013/sites/Team          
$sList = $web.Lists["Doc1"]
$dList = $web.Lists["DOC2"]
$AllFolders = $sList.Folders 
foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
    foreach($file in $Folder.Folder.Files)
    {
        write-Host "Hello"
        $sBytes = $file.OpenBinary() 
        $dFile  = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($dList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, $sBytes, $true)         
    }
}
$dList.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, but I have one doubt, files are copied into root folders of destination subsite. can't we move them into actual folders on destination ? like $dFile  = $dList.specificFolder.Files.Add($dList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, $sBytes, $true)

Comment: Of course we can copy files in specific folder. There needs to be a logic to get the folder structure info from source library and then creating that folder structure in destination and finally copying the files in respective folder like `$specificFolder.Files.Add($specificFolder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, $sBytes, $true)`. I was just showing the correct way of adding a file to folder in response to your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer after trying to get the specific folder in destination subsite. May be a little mistake I am committing so I am getting - You cannot call a method on null valued expression

Comment: Got the error and corrected, now it is working as expected. thanks a ton Nadeem.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Nadeem , since I am looping in folder structure in a specific library, can I also loop through all document libraries and create the documents also?

Comment: Sure, you can do that as well